# Find number components with lowest distribution

Tags: code-golf, integer

- Let us assume that we have number `X`.
- Let us assume that we have positive integer "components" (`C`) of this `X` number.
- We can add these components together like `C1+C2+...+Cn = X`.
- We have `N` as limit of number of components.
- We have `B` as limit of biggest component
- Distribution: if we have `[8;8;5]` then avg of components is `7`,
  distribution is `abs(8-7)+abs(8-7)+abs(5-7) = 4`
- Lowest distribution: `dist([8;8;5])=4 dist([7;7;7])=0` -> lowest
  distribution from these sets is `[7;7;7]`
- Component order does not matter.
- Components shall be the same number except one item which can be lower.

Examples

```
X = 17
N = 3
B = 8
```

- Then possible component sets are `[8;8;1]`, `[7;7;3]` and `[6;6;5]`.
- The lowest distribution between the components is in `[6;6;5]`,
  that's what we need.

---

```
X = 21
N = 3
B = 8
```

- Possible sets: `[8;8;5]` and `[7;7;7]`.
- Winner is `[7;7;7]`.

---

```
X = 22
N = 3
B = 8
```

- Possible sets: `[8;8;6]` and no more.
- Winner: `[8;8;6]`

---

---

```
X = 25
N = 3
B = 8
```

- Possible sets: - (due to B = 8)

---

I'm looking for the shortest script for this problem written in Javascript.
I have a 10 Line solution.

My solution:

```
const findComponents = (X, B, N) => {
    let S = null;
    let mainComponent = Math.ceil(X / N);
    if (mainComponent <= B){
      let otherComponent = X % mainComponent;
      S = Array(N - 1).fill(mainComponent);
      S.push(otherComponent == 0 ? mainComponent : otherComponent);
    }
    return S;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! There's a few things which need to be clarified here: 1. what does "lowest distribution" mean? 2. what should answers do if different solutions tie for lowest distribution (if that's possible?)? 3. does the order of the components matter?

Comment: Updated with some clarification, and I forgot to add that components should as big as possible. Details in the post "Update/clarification" part.

Comment: I think it all makes sense. I've voted to reopen, although I would suggest opening it up to all languages (you can state that you are particularly interested in Javascript solutions :)).

Comment: Does "components" mean "digits"?

Comment: Since the output is of the form `[Big] * (N - 1) + [Small]` and we're minimising the sum of the distance to the mean, this seems to be "Given integers \$X\$ and \$N\$ output a list of \$N-1\$ elements of value \$\lceil \frac{X}{N} \rceil\$ and one of value \$X - (N-1)(\lceil \frac{X}{N} \rceil-X)\$". As a corollary, I also think that B has no effect except for ruling out a solution (i.e. if you increase B from any point at which it allows a solution you'll get the same answer).

Comment: xnor: yes "components" mean "digits"

Comment: Jonathan, you are right, my solution is the same.

Comment: What else should I add to open this query?

Comment: I personally think it's clear like this. There are 4 open votes already, so we'll just have to wait for one more vote. One thing you could perhaps add: as mentioned by @JonathanAllan, the max \$B\$ is now only to ensure whether there is or isn't a solution. So perhaps add a test case for which there is no such result (e.g. `X=25, N=3, B=8`)?

Comment: @vpas You say above that components are "digits" I would have thought the components were either non-negative integers or positive integers. i.e. `X=44, N=4, B=12` should produce `[11,11,11,10]` rather than no output. Could you confirm either way?

Comment: X=44,N=4,B=12 should produce [11,11,11,11]

Components = digits = positive integers. (to be exact)

Comment: Added X=25,N=3,B=8 also.

Comment: @vpas thanks (I meant `X=43`) but you've addressed my question! I hope this can be reopened soon, it just needs one more re-open vote. I know it can be a little frustrating, but it's best to get a clear specification before answers pour in adhering to conflicting assumptions. I also edited to state that components are positive integers. I only suggest saying something like "when there is no possible solution you should give either a sentinel (e.g. an empty list or -1 etc.) or produce no output and terminate".

Comment: I agree with you Jonathan, so im ok with the clarification requests. Can I add my solution? I'm courios if that can be shorter or not.

Comment: I really don't see a problem with that, although most challengers do usually wait a while before doing so to allow people some time to give it a go themselves.

Comment: If there's already shorter solutions, it's perfectly fine to answer what you had. I'm sure Arnauld will come and beat mine.

Comment: What is the expected output for e.g. `12, 3, 8`?

Comment: @att: possible sets are [5;5;2] and [4;4;4], winner is [4;4;4]

Comment: added my solution for the problem

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16 10</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
÷Ċ¬>¡⁵⁸sẈ
```

A full program that accepts `X N B` and prints a list or errors if no solution is possible.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//w7fEisKsPsKh4oG14oG4c@G6iP///zE3/zP/OA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/JLW4RENToZorNTkjX0E3T0FJxUHB1k5BiSsrNSenUiG1NE9B/fD2I12H1tgdWvioceujxh3FD3d1qCsA1RnZqRko1NQogPUq5eUrFOfnlJZk5ucppOWX5qUocdVygcxXMDRXMFawgLCNDJHYRkhsUxD7/38A) (Thanks, [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)!)

...if erroring is not acceptable then \$10\$ with `s÷Ċ¥Ẉ«Ƒ⁵ȧƊ` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//c8O3xIrCpeG6iMKrxpHigbXIp8aK////MjX/M/84)) prints `0` instead.

#### How?

```
÷Ċ¬>¡⁵⁸sẈ - Main Link: integer, X; integer, N
÷         -   (X) divided by (N)
 Ċ        -   round up to an integer (let's call this R)
     ⁵    - set the right argument to the program's third argument = B
    ¡     - repeat...
   >      - ...number of times: (R) greater than? (B)
  ¬       - ...action: logical NOT
              i.e. replace R with 0 if R>B (let's call this P)
      ⁸   - chain's left argument = X
       s  - (implicit [1,2,...,X]) split into chunks of length (P)
            Note: trailing elements are kept e.g. 7s3 -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]
        Ẉ - length of each
          - implicit print
```

Comment: `22,3,8` produces wrong output. The rules say that the output must be where all integers are the same except one which can be smaller.

Comment: Uh, hmmm must've posted the wrong thing ...will need to check! Thanks @Steffan

Comment: @Steffan not sure what I had wrong so I've replaced it with a different solution entirely that's one more byte.

Comment: Here's a test suite using Zsh: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/JLW4RENToZorNTkjX0E3T0FJxUHB1k5BiSsrNSenUiG1NE9B/fD2I10VD3dOszs84eGO@Y8at1o/2rgOSAU/atxzaOmx9keNO9QVgPpqFIpTUxSUivXjVPTz8hWK83NKSzLz8/SVuGq5QBYpGJorGCtYQNhGhkhsIyS2KYj9/z8A "Zsh – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, @Steffan (...and that's better now, it felt way too long before!).

Comment: @Steffan would you know how to change that Zsh script to handle an error for the no solution cases?

Comment: I was just going to comment on that. lol. [Here](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/JLW4RENToZorNTkjX0E3T0FJxUHB1k5BiSsrNSenUiG1NE9B/fD2I12H1tgdWvioceujxh3FD3d1qCsA1RnZqRko1NQogPUq5eUrFOfnlJZk5ucppOWX5qUocdVygcxXMDRXMFawgLCNDJHYRkhsUxD7/38A)'s an updated test suite.

Comment: Sweet stuff, thanks again!

Comment: This fails for `5,4,2` (as do my answers)

Comment: @Steffan Yep, I assumed that any `N` and `X` provided would have a solution if given a high enough `B`. This code could obviously be extended to check that the length of the output is equal to the `X` at end. Note, however, that the reference implementation in the post outputs `[2,2,2,2,1]` for that input, which seems to imply we don't need to handle invalid `N,X` combinations.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `R`, <s>22</s> <s>12</s> 9 bytes

```
/⌈~≥[¹ẇvL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBUFIiLCIiLCIv4oyIfuKJpVvCueG6h3ZMIiwiIiwiMywgMTcsIDhcbjMsIDIxLCA4XG4zLCAyMiwgOFxuMywgMjUsIDgiXQ==)

*-10 bytes by porting Jonathan Allan's answer*

Outputs a positive integer for no solution.

If that's not allowed:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `R`, 10 bytes

```
/⌈~<ßQ¹ẇvL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBUFIiLCIiLCIv4oyIfjzDn1HCueG6h3ZMIiwiIiwiMywgMTcsIDhcbjMsIDIxLCA4XG4zLCAyMiwgOFxuMywgMjUsIDgiXQ==)

For no solution, produces no output.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```
(x,n,b)=>(a=[...Array(--n).fill(y=(x+n)/-~n|0),x-n*y],y>b||a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3bTUqdPJ0kjRt7TQSbaP19PQci4oSKzV0dfM09dIyc3I0KoEqtPM09XXr8moMNHUqdPO0KmN1Ku2SamoSNaGGRCfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpGJrrGOtYaGpyoQobGWIXNsIubAoRhlixYAGEBgA)

Similar to Jonathan Allan's answer.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3LTUqdPJ0kjRt7TQqbTUqtOt08zT182oMNO2Samqi9fT0HIuKEis1dIHCemmZOTkalZo6Fbp5WpWxUAOik_PzivNzUvVy8tM10jQMzXWMdSw0NblQhY0MsQsbYRc2hQhDrFiwAEIDAA) by computing `y` right away.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```
lambda x,n,b:[y:=b>=(y:=-(-x//n))and y]*~-n+[~-x%y+1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXMSc5NSEhUqdPJ0kqyiK61sk-xsNYCUroZuhb5-nqZmYl6KQmWsVp1unnZ0nW6FaqW2YSxUs3NBUWZeiUaahqG5jrGOhaYmF0zAyBBdwAhdwBQiADFqwQIIDQA)

Port of my JS answer (which is a port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer). Errors for no possible solution.

Comment: I think this works for 46: `lambda x,n,b:[z:=0--x//n]*~-n+[~-x%z+[1][z>b]]`. Probably there's a shorter way to error out when needed.

Comment: @xnor Doesn't that (and original code) fail for (5,4,2)?

Comment: Indeed it does fail for `[5,4,2]`. I'll look into it later.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅœIùʒ@P}ʒ¦Ë}θ
```

Inputs in the same order as the challenge description: \$X,N,B\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//8OFxZNJw7nKkkBQfcqSwqbDi33OuP//MjEKMwo4) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCWOj/w61HJ0cc3nlqUmSxQ0DtqUmHlh3urj2347/O/@hoQ3MdYx2LWJ1oI0MYwwjGMIUyTEx0THQMjYAsQ4hcLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ       # Get all lists of positive integers that sum to the first (implicit) input `X`
  Iù     # Only keep the lists with a length equal to the second input `N`
    ʒ    # Filter this list by:
     @   #  Check if the third (implicit) input `B` is >= the current value
      P  #  Check that it's truthy for all values in the list
    }ʒ   # After the filter: filter again:
      ¦  #  Remove the first value of the list
       Ë #  Check if all other values are the same
     }θ  # After the filter: pop and keep the last list
         # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: A port of [_@JonathanAllan_'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250878/52210) would be 12 bytes ([verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhNaEJRxf81z@87tBKh0PrtCJ8ig9vedS0Jv2/zv/oaENzHWMdi1idaCNDGMMIxjCFMkxMdEx0DI2ALEOIXCwA)), but unfortunately test cases without results would result in large output-lists instead of erroring.